# Why does express routing go a level deep instead of top-level page path?

Tags: express, routes

When using this app.js file to route an express app,

```
var itemRouter = express.Router();

app.use('/items', itemRouter);

itemRouter.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
  res.render('items');
});

itemRouter.route('/single').get(function (req, res) {
  res.render('singleItem');
});
```

why does `/single` route to http://localhost:3000/items/single and not to http://localhost:3000/single? what is telling express to add to the page path instead of create a new one?

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific, inside app.js you have assigned itemRouter to the base path "/item". There are benefits to this, since itemRouter can be kept in a separate file handling all the items sub-directories, but thats out of scope and it seems you've found your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because the middleware has `app.use`, the  route is being set to that path